# Customizing the grid panel grid line color

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to customize the Grid panel grid lines colors in silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.showgridlines%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> Setting **ShowGridLines** to **true** is not intended for use in
>   production-quality code. If you want lines inside a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), style the
>   elements within the [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to have borders. For more information, see
>   [Border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Border or Rectangle, etc for styling a Grid lines. You can create a static grid helper with attached dependency properties, which needed (for example: grid line style, visibility, etc). You should use these properties for line styling (if you will use borders then should be setted border style, rectangles - rectangle style, etc) and detect a visibility of lines. You can find some samples in internet.

As for using it. It should be used in this way:

```
<Grid GridHelper.LineVisibility="Visible" GridHelper.LineStyle="{StaticResource CustomBorderStyle}" />
```

This is a simple sample  of using static grid helper. I can not upload a code of this helper. If you understand an idea, you can start to do helper, like this. In other way you can find some sources in internet.

Comment: <Grid GridHelper.LineVisibility="Visible" GridHelper.LineStyle="{StaticResource CustomBorderStyle}" />